# How can I get the larger fish by the shore?

Tags: zelda-links-awakening

In the fishing minigame of Legend of Zelda: Link's Awakening, you pay 10 rupees to play, get 5 back if you catch a small fish (net loss of 5) and get 20 if you catch a large fish (net gain of 10).

[image]

Now, I've managed to catch the large fish on the bottom left, but I now want to get the large fish in the hole on the right.

> The fact you get a heart piece when you do is *completely* irrelevant ♫

However, no matter how I try to get the timing right and no matter how short I throw the reel (by holding right during the process), I can't just seem to get past the three small fishes. I've also tried going for the leftmost fish and then moving horizontally, but the other large fish won't let me do that.

Comment: Catch all of them and you'll get some funny dialogue out of the Fisherman, especially when you decline.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can continue playing after you've caught a fish - it's much easier to catch the big lunker in the lower right once you've removed the three smaller fish from the pond.

After you have cleared these other fish just cast out your line as normal, then let it sink a little and reel in a little. If you don't let it sink you will go too far above it. Repeat this process until you get close enough to the fish for him to notice.

Comment: ugh. I guess that means more zombie grinding for _rupees_.

Comment: BRAAAAIIIINNNSSS, err, COOOOOINNNNNNSSS

Comment: RUUUUUUUPPPEEEEEEEEEEEESSSSSSSSS!